# JavaScript Scope Query?

Tags: javascript

```
var my_var = 3;

function doIt() {

    console.log( my_var ); //why undefined?

    var my_var = 7;

    return ++my_var; 
} 

doIt(); // returns 8 as expected
```

Why my_var returns *undefined* instead global value (3)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You defined `my_var` as a local variable inside of your function. JavaScript [hoists](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) variables to the top of the scope, so your function really acts like this:

```
function doIt() {
    var my_var;

    console.log( my_var );

    my_var = 7;

    return ++my_var; 
}
```

Comment: I have been doing JS for long time but didn't know about this. Learnt something new today. Cheers Blender!